# Superset: How to Change Time Grain option dynamically

Tags: apache-superset

I have 3 time-series bar charts with different time grain values (day, week, and month) on Superset. The rest is the same.

Is there a way to make it (time grain selection) a filter or something so that I don't have to build very similar 3 charts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select the "Show SQL Granularity Dropdown" when creating a filter box. This will allow you to change the time grain in the filter and allow you to have 1 chart, e.g. a time series table that you can change the time grain for allowing you to display DoD, WoW, YoY, etc.

Comment: Dropdown has 14 options but i only want 3 options (day, month, year). How do that?

Answer (score 3):

Now with native dashboard filters in version 1.5 and beyond, you can click `+ ADD/EDIT FILTERS`, then `+Add filters and dividers`, then `Filter`, then for Filter Type choose `Time Grain`.  Then the user will be given a dropdown menu to control the time granularity.